# Shell substitution in subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

Could someone point to the right way to do shell substitution using subprocess module. As a trivial example, consider the below case

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l', '/tmp/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`'], shell=True)
```

The below variations have been tried without success

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l', '/tmp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")'], shell=True)
    result = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l', '/tmp/date +"%Y-%m-%d"'], shell=True)
```

Also, would subprocess.Popen be the better way of doing this rather than check_output.

Comment: I am more interested in knowing how shell substitution works with subprocess module. Yes, I am aware of those, I am just trying to figure out what would be the best way to go about when a situation where one needs shell substitution arises, I will edit the question to this effect, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell substitution only happens in shells, and you're not running one. There is no way to quote this to make it work.

Instead, do the shell's job yourself:

```
import subprocess
date = subprocess.check_output(['date', '+%Y-%m-%d']).rstrip("\n")
result = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l', '/tmp/' + date])
print(result)
```

Alternatively, you can run the command in a shell. This requires less thinking, but is more fragile:

```
result = subprocess.check_output('ls -l /tmp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")', shell=True)
```

Comment: In python2 result = subprocess.check_output('ls -l /tmp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")', shell=True) results in an error.

Yes, I am aware I can offload that part to python functions, but I am interested in knowing how i can run it with the subprocess module, I did try it with a variation of shell=True but it did not work
Also, it should probably be date = subprocess.check_output(['date', '+%Y-%m-%d']).decode("utf-8").rstrip("\n")

Comment: It works in python2 on my system. What error are you getting?

Comment: My bad, it does return the right results, will mark this as the asnwer